# on click is not working due to change in td width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a strange problem, that i have a `<table>` and on `<td>` there is a text box and on the next `<td>` there is an `add` button. In the text box, there is an `onblur` function which will hide the textbox and create a `<span>` for the textbox value. the span has a lesser width than textbox .

Also there is an add button `Onclick` event,  My problem is that when we type something on text box and then click on add button, `onblur' event works first and click is not working because the click button position changes when the text box hides.

Anyone help me what I have to do get the both event works and i want these event should work separately

```
<Table>
<tr>
<td><Span>bla<Span><input type="text" onblur="hideTextboxCreateNewSpan()"/></td>
<td><a onclick="AddNewTextBox()">Add</a></td>
</tr>
</Table>
```

This is my table structure Sample and i have tons of code in these both function i cant copy here any one please help me

Comment: add your script also

Comment: Move clickable stuff above or to the left of stuff that disappears

Comment: Js which is using now contain huge codes that's y i didnt add js i have added the scenario

Comment: you simply add the AddNewTextBox() Function Script

Comment: Try this: `onclick="AddNewTextBox();return false;"`.

Comment: can you please create jsfiddle it will be easier to solve your problem

Comment: @Sreerejith S S create a jsfiddle and give the link

Comment: I solved the problem by placing the add button to the textbox row Thanks all for the help anyway

Answer (score 0):

Try using `setTimeout`, then the button will be clicked before the `hideTextBoxCreateNewSpan` is called:

```
onblur="setTimeout(hideTextboxCreateNewSpan, 0);"
```